# Добавить событие по ID на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, есть вот такой `html`:

```
<div class="item_name_582k">
<div class="item_top_date" id="582k">19/03</div>
<div class="info_block" id="name_582k">
 Бла бла
</div>
</div>
<div class="item_name_583k">
<div class="item_top_date" id="583k">19/03</div>
<div class="info_block" id="name_583k">
 Бла бла
</div>
</div>
```

........ и так далее

Как организовать добавление класса или показ при наведении на `jQuery`.
Пробовал так:

```
$("div.item_top_date").hover(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("div.info_block[id='"+id+"']").stop();
        $("div.info_block[id='"+id+"']").animate({
             opacity: 0.0
        }, 10);
    },
    function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("div.info_block[id='"+id+"']").stop();
        $("div.info_block[id='"+id+"']").animate({
             opacity: 1.0
        }, 10);
    });
```

Но не получается, отображаются все блоки сразу!

Answer (score 2):

Селектор вы неправильно написали. Нужно написать вот так:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('div#name_'+id).stop();
```

Ну и все остальные селекторы для *name_XXXk* идентично этому.